# Long Navigation bar introducing horizontal scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have designed a Navbar in which the drop down are absolutely positioned with respect to their parent list items (Main menu list is `position: relative` and submenus `position: absolute`).

My navbar 's main list is long (stretches till right-end of page). So when I hover on the last main menu item, then my drop-down occupies it's width and the page introduces a horizontal scroll (goes outside the body content).

I want the dropdown's on extreme ends of the page to open from right to left so that they lie within the body itself and no scroll is introduced.

How can I achieve this??? Please Help.

I have designed a Navigation Bar as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Categories</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Graphic design</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Development tools</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Web design</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    position: relative;
}
#menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

#menu ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 195px;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}

#menu ul a {    
    padding: 10px;
    width: 175px;
    _height: 10px; /*IE6 only*/
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: none;
}
```

Comment: Try this css #menu{overflow:hidden;}

Comment: @RohitBatham That would hide the submenus.

Answer (score 1):

```
#menu li:last-child ul {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider providing some explanation!

Comment: @Niels: This will only cater to the last dropdown. It also happens that the submenu of the second-last dropdown (or previous) expands and introduces the scroll. In that case?

Comment: @Console it's not self-explanatory enough?  :P   @Siddharth use `nth-last-child` constructs then.